# Best way to change specific property of set of controlsin VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a set of controls on my form and i want to enable/disable some of them. what is the best way?
Hint: I don't want to change all controls available in my form.

Answer (score 1):

If your meaning from "enable/disable" is "preventing user from changing them", then you can do this:

```
THE_NAME_OF_CONTROL.Enabled = False 'Disable a control with THE_NAME_OF_CONTROL Name
```

And

```
THE_NAME_OF_CONTROL.Enabled = True 'Enable a control with THE_NAME_OF_CONTROL Name
```

Or you can put all of your controls in a "Group Box" and disable/enable whole group box.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for latency (My windows crashed and finally i re-installed it). I'm aware of that property. In fact, I want to change that for a set of controls by writing minimum code. Adding controls to an array and using a For Each maybe a good way, but i'm not sure this is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want change controls outside of form, then create a public property or method which do it, instead of making controls public

```
Public Class MyForm
    Inherits Form

    Private _MyCheckBoxControl As CheckBox
    Private _MyTextBoxControl As TextBox

    Private _IsGroupOfControlsEnabled As Boolean
    Public Property IsGroupOfControlsEnabled As Boolean
    Get
        Return _IsGroupOfControlsEnabled As Boolean
    End Get
    Set (value As Boolean)
        _IsGroupOfControlsEnabled = value
        'Update controls
        _MyCheckBoxControl.Enabled = _IsGroupOfControlsEnabled 
        _MyTextBoxControl.Enabled = _IsGroupOfControlsEnabled 
    End Set

End Class
```